# How to define Image interpolation quality on windows 8 Application?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-runtime, bitmapimage

I'm making an windows 8 application.

I've a ScrollViewer with an Image inside. 
The source image is really big, and the rendering with the Image is really bad (because the Image is really smaller than the source image, so the scaling make the result ugly).

Here is how I set the source image:

```
var baseUri = new Uri("ms-appx:///");
var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri(baseUri, CurrentLocalization.MapPath));
MapImage.Source = bitmapImage;
```

My question is : how can I set the interpolation quality of the Image to have a better rendering? I don't find any ScalingMode option or InterpolationQuality...

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use DirectX or SharpDX to achieve such results.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But how can I use those technologies within a ScrollViewer? Do you have any links or tutorial that may help?